# Javascript file returning 'undefined' with variable

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a JavaScript file which is working great, except it's not returning one field. They're all from a SharePoint list, it's showing 'undefined' but I thought I'd defined it at the start?

The returned information shows on a HTML pafe

The variable I'm having the problem with is `'var txtfurtherinfo ="";'`? Everything else is showing fine.  Any help is appreciated. The JavaScript is below, it's later called as DeviceInformation...

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtName = "";
var txtOverview = "";
var txtAccessories = "";
var txtDevicetype = "";
var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
var txtTrafficlight = "";
var imgDevicePicture = "";
var tempLCS2 = "";
var txtfurtherinfo ="";
var HTML = "<h3>Desktop</h3>";
var Laptop = "Y"
var Tabs="Y" 

var query = "http://example.com/sites/it/ITInfrastructure/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";






var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var NameofDevice = item.Title;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
        var DeviceKind = item.DevicetypeValue;
        var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
        var DevicePriority = item.PriorityValue;
        var DeviceImage = item.DeviceImage;
        var DeviceInformation = item.furtherinfo;

        txtTitle = "<p>" + NameofDevice + "<p>"; 
        txtName = "<p>" + NameofDevice + "</p>" +  DeviceKind + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>";
        txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";
        txtfurtherinfo ="<p>" + DeviceInformation +  "</p>";
        imgDevicePicture = "<img src='" + DeviceImage + "'>";

    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('#devicetitle').append($(txtTitle));
    $('devicename').append(txtName);
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);
    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);
    $('#furtherinfo').append(txtfurtherinfo);
    $('#imageContainer').append("<img src='/sites/IT/ITInfrastructure/SiteAssets/"+txtTrafficlight.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')+".png' />");
    $('.deviceimage').append(imgDevicePicture); 

});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual response to the HTTP request to verify that each "item" really contains a "furtherinfo" property?

Comment: Is this really a minimal example of your code that produces the problem you are having?

Comment: Are you expecting  `getDeviceDetails` to return something else than `undefined`? (after beautifying your code, and removing all non-essential code, I could see that you make an asynchronous Ajax call inside the function, that, from the perspective of the call to getDecviceDetails might happen sometime in the future.)

Comment: Every item variable is returning a result to the HTML table. So for example:

  var txtOverview = "";
   var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
   txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
   $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));

uses the div tag of "deviceoverview" in the HTML table which displays a laptops specifications entered in a SharePoint field.

I want  var DeviceInformation = item.furtherinfo; to return multiple lines of text entered in a new SharePoint field instead of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the times that you get undefined in javascript is when you are trying to access information that is not defined in the scope. 
Your item variable likely does not have any any member-variable called "furtherinfo".
Based on the notation for the other member-variables, it could be called "FurtherInfo", "furtherInfo", or something similar.